# Setting display-property via jQuery - not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have the following problem. I have this jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("thead.opening").click(function () {
        var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        alert("INTO second function, chrome: " + is_chrome);
        $(this).next().css('width', '10000000 em');
        $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
        alert($(this).next().css('display'));
    })
});
```

When the user is clicking on the `thead` (having `class="opening"`) of a table and this CSS is set to the `tbody` element of the same table (represented by `$(this).next()`):

```
style="display: table-row-group;
```

This works fine for FireFox and Internet Explorer but it doesn't work in Chrome.

I've obtained the following behavior (as you can see in the previous code snippet I have put some `alert()` to debug the code):

1. `INTO second function, chrome: true`
2. Then it is sets the CSS property as I expect:

   ```
   $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
   ```

   and when perform the second `alert()` that represent the CSS settings for my `tbody` element:

   ```
   $(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group');
   ```

   it print the expected value: `table-row-group` and it is correctly sets because I see the alert popup and under it my page correctly rendered
3. When I click on the OK button of the alert popup it disappear and my `tbody` element have some visualization problem, in particular what happens is that the `tbody` element have set `style="display: block;"` instead `style="display: table-row-group;"`, this is my obtained `tbody`

Seems as Chrome first correctly sets the `display: table-row-group;"` (because I see the `tbody` element in the correct position under the second alert popup) and then automatically sets it to `display: block;"` when the Ok button of this popup is clicked.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your code in fiddle ?

Comment: What happens when you use `console.log()` instead of `alert()`?

Comment: Unexpected reason. `$(this).next().css('width', '10000000 em');` remove the space : `10000000 em` to `10000000em`

Answer (score 2):

```
10000000 em
```

will cause error in css.

change it to `10000000em`

http://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/0nh72pg0/
when you try this link, will it also remove the table display?
any other functions which could remove style properties?
are both style properties removed?

Comment: I can confirm that jsfiddle works in Chrome 42. I get `style="width: 10000000em; display: table-row-group;"` when I click the table head.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why Chrome should reset your style; the error is probably elsewhere in the code. Create a minimal example to make sure that there isn't a second event handler which does this unexpected reset.

The next thing is to disable plugins. There might be a plugin which you have installed in Chrome which changes the CSS.

Comment: look at spaces in cs properties

Comment: @Mephiztopheles: Well, the width won't work but that shouldn't affect the `display` property.

Comment: that's what i saw after my comment, thats why you got + :)

Answer (score 0):

This could happen, because the alert is more important in the eventqueue of chrome. What happens if you try this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("thead.opening").click(function () {
        var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
        alert("INTO second function, chrome: " + is_chrome);
        $(this).next().css({
            width: '10000000em',
            display: 'table-row-group'
        });
        setTimeout( function() {
            console.log($(this).next().css('display'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: alert will halt js but wont break it. what you changed will work too, if you remove space in css property. additionally it is faster to set all proerties in one line trather than 2 lines

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other style that is defined for your display attribute?
But if it works for firefox, it should work for chrome.

you could try -

```
$(this).next().css('display', 'table-row-group !important');
```

Comment: If I put the !important stop to works also in FireFox and Explorer

Comment: `!important` shouldn't be necessary for inline styles; they should always take precedence over styles from CSS files :-/

Comment: seems like there is a bug in jquery which does not accept !important as above.
try -
.className{
  display: table-row-group !important;
} 
$("body").addClass("className");